# Calling a Java web service using server authentication from .net

Tags: .net, web-services, authentication, ssl

I have a web service I want to call:

https://someserver.com/Service

The service is built on a IBM WAS server in Java.  It is using SSL authentication so on the WAS server a certificate was created and they sent us the public .cer file and a WSDL file.

On my side I have a .net application that is set up based on the WSDL file to consume the service.  I installed the .cer file on the calling machine using keystore (a java application) per the Service developer's instructions.

When I try to consume the service I get the error:
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

What should I be doing in order to get the SSL channel working?  Does keystore's installation of the certificate work with .net applications?  Do I need to use the certificate in another way?

Update:
I found I can install the certificate on my machine by double-clicking it... but that seems to have had no effect and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a WCF client and in the binding set the security to message and configure the binding to use the certificate.

Have a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733098.aspx

This is for X509 (probably not relevant for you):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733102.aspx

Comment: Great.  Thanks.  I can't seem to get it to work yet, but seems like this is the answer.